# How to read all lines from console and output them to console in Scheme?

Tags: io, scheme

I want to read all lines from console and put them in a list, how to do it in Scheme?

Say, when the program is running, user will input many lines in the console:

```
aaaa
1111
bbbbb
ccc
2323
dddd
4444
```

And my Scheme code will read all of them and filtering the numbers and output them to console.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that keeps reading from the default input port and displays it to the default output port.

```
(define (read-and-display)
  (let ((x (read)))
    (if (not (eof-object? x))
      (begin
        (display x)
        (newline)
        (read-and-display)))))
```

If your Scheme implementation supports `unless`, the above function can be simplified to:

```
(define (read-and-display)
  (let ((x (read)))
    (unless (eof-object? x)
        (display x)
        (newline)
        (read-and-display))))
```

Comment: Instead of the `(if (not <condition>) (begin <body>))` idiom you can simply use `(unless <condition> <body>)`, it'll be shorter and clearer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, Is `unless` part of the Scheme standard? If it is, agree with you that using `unless` is a better option.

Comment: Is not standard, but very common in many interpreters and easily implemented as a macro if not present - I bet your interpreter already has it ;) . Same thing with `when`, it's just like `unless` but without the `not` part.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez `when` and `unless` are standard as of R6RS and R7RS.